# VBE How do you use Filldown with the WEEKNUM Function

Tags: excel, vba

I want cell E2 to pull the WEEKNUM from cell D2, and then repeat for the length of my data set.

```
Sub WeekNumTest()
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKNUM(RC[-1])"
Range("E2").Select
Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

The weeknum is pulling correctly for cell E2, but the formula is not continuing for the rest of my data.

Comment: You only have one cell selected, there is nothing to fill down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variables and find the extent of range.

Then set all the formulas at once.

```
Sub WeekNumTest()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 5), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row, 5))

Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKNUM(RC[-1])"

End Sub
```